# How to reduce a 3 dimensional tensor to 2 dimensional one using pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I am facing an error when working with my CNN model, that error being:

```bash
The size of tensor a (4) must match the size of tensor b (512) at non-singleton dimension 1
```

This happens as I am trying to reduce my input's dimensions, such that it adheres to what I have in mind for my use case.

Therefore, the question is how can I reduce

```py
torch.Size([512, 4, 1000])
```

from a 3D vector to the following 2D one:

```py
torch.Size([512, 1])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reducing `[512, 4, 1000]` to `[512, 1]` will result in the loss of a lot of data because the product of dimensions `2` and `3 (4 \* 1000 = 4000)` cannot be compressed into `1` without losing data.

As long as you are aware of what you are doing though you could do something like this:

```py
input_tensor = torch.randn(512, 4, 1000)  # your tensor
output_tensor = input_tensor.mean(dim=[1,2], keepdim=True)
print(output_tensor.shape)  # should output torch.Size([512, 1])
```

But if you want to preserve your data you are better off doing something like this:

```py
input_tensor = torch.randn(512, 4, 1000)  # your tensor
output_tensor = input_tensor.view(512, -1)
print(output_tensor.shape)  # should output torch.Size([512, 4000])
```

***Note:** You may already know this but just in case; the `-1` acts as a placeholder that PyTorch will fill in to keep the correct number of total elements in the tensor*

Comment: `input_tensor.mean(dim=[1,2], keepdim=True)` would return a dim of `[512, 1, 1]`, so you'd also need `squeeze` to make it `[512, 1]`: `input_tensor.mean(dim=[1,2], keepdim=True).squeeze(dim=-1)`

Comment: is it possible to squeeze or unsqueeze the data instead of using mean value ?

Comment: meanwhile I tried the code, however the matrix converted to torch.Size([512, 1, 1]) not torch.Size([512, 1]. Have I missed something?

Comment: @heemayl good callout thank you